# how can i fix my bones and the mesh connected to it?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

Hi I'm trying to rig a character from Mixamo (I swapped out the default rig for a more complex one) all the vertex groups are in the right place but when I use automatic weights or empty weights, it moves my mesh out of the way so the bone isn't even touching.

does anyone know what's happening and how to solve it?
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry, the file's too big